# Chrono library compilation issue with g++ and clang++

Tags: ubuntu, time, g++, clang++, c++-chrono

**Hi all I am trying to work with epoch in chrono library, but I am getting different results while running with g++ and clang++ can anyone help me?**

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using std::string;

uint64_t timeToEpoch(uint64_t day, uint64_t month, uint64_t year, uint64_t hour, uint64_t min, uint64_t second, uint64_t microsecond){
    string timeT = std::to_string(day) + "-" + std::to_string(month) + "-" + std::to_string(year) + " " + std::to_string(hour) + ":" + std::to_string(min) + ":" + std::to_string(second);
    char *time_T = new char[(timeT.length() + 1)];
    strcpy(time_T, timeT.c_str());
    struct tm tm;
    strptime(time_T, "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S", &tm);
    uint64_t t = mktime(&tm);
    t = (t * 1000000) + microsecond;
    return t; 
}

string epochToTime(uint64_t epochTime){
    string timeT;
    uint64_t microsecond = epochTime % 1000000;
    time_t epochTimeInSec = (epochTime - microsecond) / 1000000;
    char time_T[21];
    strftime(time_T, 20, "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S", localtime(&epochTimeInSec));
    timeT = time_T;
    timeT = timeT + ":" + std::to_string(microsecond);
    return timeT; 
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Year changed 2004 to 2005\n";
    uint64_t time_info_1 = timeToEpoch(31, 12, 2004, 23, 59, 59, 999999);
    uint64_t time_info_2 = timeToEpoch(1, 1, 2005, 0, 0, 0, 9);
    std::cout << "First timestamp in epoch :" << time_info_1 << "\n";
    std::cout << "Second timestamp in epoch: " << time_info_2 << "\n\n";
    std::cout << "Deffernce between both timestamp in microsecond: " << (time_info_2 - time_info_1) << "\n\n";
    std::cout << "First timestamp converted from epoch: " << epochToTime(time_info_1) << "\n";
    std::cout << "Second timestamp converted from epoch: " << epochToTime(time_info_2) << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

**This is my c++ code which is working properly with g++**
[image: This is my c++ code which is working properly with g++]
**But not working with clang**
[image: But not working with clang]

Answer (score 0):

You aren't actually using any of the C++ chrono library.  You are using the C timing API (which is fine, but somewhat error prone).

I'm not able to exactly reproduce your output, however I believe that if you change:

```
struct tm tm;
```

to:

```
struct tm tm{};
tm.tm_isdst = -1;
```

that this will fix your problem.  It is best to zero all fields of a `tm`, except that `tm_isdst == 0` means daylight saving is not in effect.  But `tm_isdst == -1` means that the daylight saving information is not available (so `mktime` will attempt to compute it).

---

A C++20 solution using `<chrono>` might look like this:

```
std::chrono::microseconds
timeToEpoch(std::chrono::local_time<std::chrono::microseconds> tp)
{
    using namespace std::chrono;

    auto tp_utc = current_zone()->to_sys(tp);
    return tp_utc.time_since_epoch();
}

std::string 
epochToTime(std::chrono::microseconds epochTime)
{
    using namespace std::chrono;

    auto tp = current_zone()->to_local(sys_time<microseconds>{epochTime});
    return std::format("{:%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S}", tp);
}
```

This is much simpler, but changes the API for the client somewhat.  The `uint64_t` is changed to `std::chrono::microseconds`.  And the calls to `timeToEpoch` now look like:

```
auto time_info_1 = timeToEpoch(local_days{31d/12/2004} + 23h + 59min + 59s + 999999us);
auto time_info_2 = timeToEpoch(local_days{1d/1/2005} + 9us);
```

The format of the output will also change slightly to:

```
Year changed 2004 to 2005
First timestamp in epoch : 1104555599999999µs
Second timestamp in epoch: 1104555600000009µs

Difference between both timestamps in microsecond: 10µs

First timestamp converted from epoch:  31-12-2004 23:59:59.999999
Second timestamp converted from epoch: 01-01-2005 00:00:00.000009
```

---

You didn't mention what compiler you were using.

As I write this, MSVC is shipping C++20 `<chrono>`.  Gcc has implemented but not yet shipped it:  [Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/LhroKdVp5qlVtcP8).  LLVM has yet to implement it.

I have a [free, open-source preview of this library](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date) that works with C++11/14/17 that you could use.  The syntax is slightly different as shown below:

```
#include "date/tz.h"
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

std::chrono::microseconds
timeToEpoch(date::local_time<std::chrono::microseconds> tp)
{
    auto tp_utc = date::current_zone()->to_sys(tp);
    return tp_utc.time_since_epoch();
}

std::string 
epochToTime(std::chrono::microseconds epochTime)
{
    using namespace date;
    using namespace std::chrono;

    auto tp = current_zone()->to_local(sys_time<microseconds>{epochTime});
    return format("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S", tp);
}

int main()
{
    using namespace date;
    using namespace std::chrono;

    std::cout << "Year changed 2004 to 2005\n";
    auto time_info_1 = timeToEpoch(local_days{31_d/12/2004} + 23h + 59min + 59s + 999999us);
    auto time_info_2 = timeToEpoch(local_days{1_d/1/2005} + 9us);
    std::cout << "First timestamp in epoch : " << time_info_1 << "\n";
    std::cout << "Second timestamp in epoch: " << time_info_2 << "\n\n";
    std::cout << "Difference between both timestamp in microsecond: " << (time_info_2 - time_info_1) << "\n\n";
    std::cout << "First timestamp converted from epoch:  " << epochToTime(time_info_1) << "\n";
    std::cout << "Second timestamp converted from epoch: " << epochToTime(time_info_2) << "\n";
}
```

For g++-12 I highly recommend compiling with `-DUSE_OS_TZDB` on the command line.  [Here are more detailed building instructions.](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/tz.html#Installation)